# convert a string into another format

Tags: erlang

I would like to convert the binary string `<<"abc">>` into the following string `"<a><b><c>"` .
In other words, each byte shall be written between one "less than" char and one "greater than" char.

I suppose that the function is recursive ? Note that abc is just an example !

Comment: It would be really helpful if you write the sample output you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
1>lists:flatten([[$<,C,$>]||C<-binary_to_list(<<"abc">>)]).
"<a><b><c>"
```

alternative

```
lists:flatmap(fun(C)-> [$<,C,$>] end,binary_to_list(<<"abc">>)).
```

or

```
f(C) -> [$<,C,$>].
lists:flatmap(fun f/1,binary_to_list(<<"abc">>)).
```

Comment: Oh ! and is it possible to add function into flatten. For example, if the C is b then don't put < and > ?

Comment: Well, not into lists:flatten/1 because it only take one parameter that shall be a list. lists:flatmap/2 on the other hand. Please see edit.

Comment: Is it not possible with foreach (fun,List) ? I don't understand the notion of flatten ...

Comment: Reference is available on erlang.org or http://erldocs.com/R13B03/ . To learn some basic maybe http://learnyousomeerlang.com/content would be a good read. Accepting the post that helped you the most wit your question is also always appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient if you want a flat list would probably be:

```
fr(<<C,Rest/binary>>) ->
    [$<,C,$>|fr(Rest)];
fr(<<>>) -> [].
```

This expansion is similar to what a list/binary comprehension expands to.

Answer (score 1):

Use a binary comprehension:

```
2> [[$<, C, $>] || <<C:1/binary>> <= <<"abc">>].
[[60,<<"a">>,62],[60,<<"b">>,62],[60,<<"c">>,62]]
```

So you don't have to process the binary into a list first and then work on it. It is probably a bit faster, especially for large lists, so if performance matter to you, it may be a viable alternative option.

Comment: This is a good solution if performance is important and if the result of this will be sent over the socket or file or other IO

Comment: Why build new one-byte binaries? `[[$<, C, $>] || <<C>> <= <<"abc">>]` should give the same result in iolist interpretation, but simpler in structure: `["<a>","<b>","<c>"]`.

Answer (score 1):

this answer is probably not best one in terms of efficiency(i didn't compare it to other solutions) but it certainly helps to understand how you can invent your own iterators over different collections in erlang aimed for achieving your specific goal instead of using predefined iterators

```
  fr(<<>>, Output) -> Output;
  fr(<<"b", Rest/binary>>, Output) ->
    fr(Rest, <<Output, "b">>);
  fr(<<C:8, Rest/binary>>, Output) ->
    fr(Rest, <<Output/binary, $<, C:8, $>>>).

  f(Input) -> fr(Input, <<>>).
```

P.S. it looks like this solution is actually the most efficient :)

Comment: You didn't compare it to other solutions? You should! I bet your code compiled with HiPE will outperform any solution in other answers currently available.

Comment: Could be, I would still prefer to point out the idea behind that code - tail recursion and it's use in designing complex and efficient iterators

Comment: I could imagine building up the binary in the tail-call parameter is a wee bit faster than many of the other solutions.